# Передача данных из JavaScript в php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Всем привет, делаю форум на php и передаю данные из js в php.
На странице выскакивают какие-то символы, больше на ней ничего нет.
Вот код:
PHP

````
```
<?php
    $connect = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=*****;charset=UTF8", '******', '*****');
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $date = date('H:i:s');
        $query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO ******.comments (username, comment, data) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date'");
    }

    $comments = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM ******.comments ORDER BY data DESC");
    $comments = $comments->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($comments){
        foreach($comments as $comment){

            echo "{$comment['data']} . {$comment['username']}";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "{$comment['comment']}";
            echo "<br>";

        }
    }else{
        echo "Пока нет ни одного комментария :(";
    }
?>
```
````

HTML:

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<h2>Форум</h2>

<div class="block">
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <div class="block-comment">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="r" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="10" rows="5" class="r" placeholder="Ваш комментарий" required></textarea>
        <input type="button" id="form-bt">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text\javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```
````

JS:

````
```
$(document).on('click', '#form-bt', function(){
    var comment = $("#comment");
    var username = $("#username");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            comment: comment,
            username: username,
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert("Наконец-то всё получилось!");
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('ERROR');
        }
    })
})
```
````

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А где сами "файлы" или хотя бы поля для загрузки файлов? И зачем два раза подключать скрипт `form.js`?

Comment: Как минимум ошибка в запросе, после VALUES не закрыта скобка ```$query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO ******.comments (username, comment, data) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date')");```

Comment: Скобку добавил, всё также.

Comment: Вы можете нормально объяснить свою проблему? При чем здесь пердача `ФАЙЛОВ`? Вы никак не взаимодействуете с файлами. Вы просто пытаетесь записать в базу данных комментарий для юзера с определенным username.

Comment: Ну и пытаетесь Вы туда записать jQuery объект, а не значение из поля. Так как для получения значения нужно заменить `$("#comment")` и `$("#username")` на `$("#comment").val()` и `$("#username").val()` соответственно.

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибся

Comment: val добавил, ошибка остаётся

Comment: Так а саму ошибку может тогда покажете, для понимания в чем проблема состоит?)

Comment: РџРѕРєР° РЅРµС‚ РЅРё РѕРґРЅРѕРіРѕ РєРѕРјРµРЅС‚Р°СЂРёСЏ :(

Comment: Сейчас на страничке не должно ничего возникать, так как на успешный запрос стоит лишь ```alert```. Кстати, он срабатывает?

Comment: Нет, только символы

Comment: Поменяйте js. Во-первых, ```$(document).on('load', function() {...}```, а внутри ```$('#form').submit(function() {...}```. И уже туда переменные и ajax запрос

Comment: Всё появилось, похоже сайт прогрузился. Но сообщения не выводятся.

Comment: У Вас на `success` просто `alert("Наконец-то всё получилось!");`.

Comment: .........И что?